# SQL Query to fetch final data for hierarchal configuration tables in a single query

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

I have two tables i.e. config_attr and config. I am working with MySQL 8.0.32.

config_attr -> This table has attribute name and its default value.
config -> This table has overriden or current value of any attribute which is present in config_attr for a particular client.

Below is a sample structure for both tables

```
CREATE TABLE config_attr (
   id INT,
   name VARCHAR,
   value VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE config (
   id INT,
   clientId INT,
   configAttrId INT,
   value VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (configAttrId) REFERENCES config_attr(id)
);
```

Currently I am fetching the data separately using individual query and then using code to override default values.

However, I want to explore if there is any other way using which I can fetch the final overriden data in a single query.

Below is an example:

config_attr

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | v1 |
| 2 | n2 | v2 |

config

| configAttrId | clientId | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | v3 |

Query Output expected for client 10:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| n1 | v3 |
| n2 | v2 |

Answer (score 1):

try coalesce with left join

```sql
SELECT 
    ca.name,
    COALESCE(c.value, ca.value) AS value
FROM 
    config_attr ca
LEFT JOIN 
    config c ON ca.id = c.configAttrId AND c.clientId = 10;
```